# Padding to list item?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a small navigation here. jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/s3king93/yjKdR/

Is there any way to add padding to the link items without having the text get larger or move?

I'd like it to ideal look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOmfr.png

Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-1">
    <ul class="list-style-1">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">INFLUENCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CLASSES</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ANDREWS VIDEO BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.list-1 {
    padding:none;
    float: right;
    clear:right;
    padding-right: 27px;
}

.list-style-1 {
    padding-top: 26px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Bell Gothic Std Light";
    font-size: 20px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #2A2A2A;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #2A2A2A;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #69E0F6;
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 70px;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #69E0F6;
    background-color: #2A2A2A
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "keep coming up"?

Comment: Sorry I mean the grey background color. Basically the text enlarges and moves when I hover over the link. Instead is there any way to have the text stay the same place while adding padding to the link?

Comment: I'd like it to ideally look like this http://i.imgur.com/0zDt0vR.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<ul>` is already a block-element by default so you don't need a div around it.

Plus, on `a:hover` you have `padding-right` set to `70px`. That's why your list is moving when you're hovering. I don't understand though why you have that padding on hover. If you remove the paddings on hover your list will remain where it is.

[Is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/R9L5j/)

Comment: Thats EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Thank you so you much, I see now where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting on the padding when you hover over the links, and that extra padding is making the link go past the end of the DIV. FOr this reason, the browser pushes it back so it all fits in the DIV.

You should assign it before hover (on a:link instead of a:hover), and the link won't move.

This CSS should do what you want:

```
.list-1 {
    padding:none;
    float: right;
    clear:right;


}


.list-style-1 {
    padding-top: 26px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Bell Gothic Std Light";
    font-size: 20px;
}


a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #2A2A2A;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

 a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #2A2A2A;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #69E0F6;
    background-color: #2A2A2A;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #69E0F6;
    background-color: #2A2A2A
}
```

See it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yjKdR/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the padding consistent when hovered.

Move the padding from `a:hover` to `a:link`. I'd also suggest qualifying those styles so they don't apply to *every* link on the page:

```
.list-style-1 a:link {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

.list-style-1 a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #2A2A2A;
}

.list-style-1 a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #69E0F6;
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
}
```

Comment: Edited for clarification. Here is what I'm trying to create. http://i.imgur.com/0zDt0vR.png

Answer (score -1):

Remove the padding properties and set the a tag to display block.

```
.list-1 {
    padding:none;
    float: right;
    clear:right;
 }

.list-style-1 a{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjKdR/3/)